# Looking for a function (or a macro) to return a boost::scoped_lock

Tags: c++, function, boost, shortcut, scoped-lock

I'm looking for code shortening idea. I'm using `boost::scoped_lock` to lock a `boost::mutex` but I want to shorten the amount of code I'm writing.

Currently I have a `mutex` defined in my class and the member field called `_sync`. When I want to lock, I have to write:

```
scoped_lock<mutex> lock(_sync);
```

The tricky part is that this is a scoped lock, so I assume that if I write a static function to return the scoped_lock, then it will unlock as soon as it gets out of the function scope of the static function:

```
static scoped_lock<mutex> lock(mutex& sync)
{
    return scoped_lock<mutex>(sync);
}
```

This approach would make it really easy to type:

```
public void Object::modify()
{
    lock(_sync); // <-- nice and short! ;)

    // do something to modify the object
    //..
    // the mutex is unlocked when we leave the scope of modify
}
```

Is my assumption correct? Will the `scoped_lock` unlock immediately when it's returned by my static function?

Comment: Why don't you typedef `scoped_lock<mutex>` with a short name? That makes it easy to type.

Comment: @Lirik: OK. Now that I understand I have removed my half of the conversation as it seems you are not breaking encapsulation.

Comment: @Martin... I removed all my comments to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#define LOCK(a) scoped_lock<mutex> scopedLockVar(a)

public void Object::modify()
{
    LOCK(_sync); // <-- nice and short! ;)

    // do something to modify the object
    //..
    // the mutex is unlocked when we leave the scope of modify
}
```

You should use a safe name for the define... The compiler just uses find and replace for defines...

Comment: `__lockVar` is a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: @GMan : Oops, didn't know that... changed it. Knew i should avoid 2 __ at the beginning of a variable name.

Comment: @Yochai : Two consecutive underscores anywhere in the name, not just at the beginning, is illegal.

Comment: Just randomly naming a variable for the example... removed underscores altogether..

Comment: That all said, I think if you (@Lirik) find typing it out too much, if you're going to use a macro go all the way and just make a class-specific internal macro that's only visible during the implementation of the functions: `#define OBJECT_LOCK scoped_lock<mutex> _scoped_lock_var_do_not_use_(_sync);` Then just throw `OBJECT_LOCK` at the type of all your functions. Simplest of all. It's not like you're going to be passing a different lock to the macro so no need having you type that too every time, nor should you try to make this some utility macro since it's so simple.

Comment: What if you want to lock two mutexes in the same scope?

Comment: @Nemo: Then change the macro.

Comment: @nemo @gman `#define LOCK(a) scoped_lock<mutex> scopedLockVar##a(a)`

Comment: `#define LOCK(a,b) scoped_lock<mutex> scopedLockVar(a); scoped_lock<mutex> scopedLockVar(b)`

Comment: @GMan the other reason I want to do this is to get a little bit closer to the C#/java style of locking, because we're a C# shop and most of the other developers have never touched C++. I hope that this way it will make it a little easier for them to follow the C++ code and it will make it easier to write code.

Answer (score 6):

Don't ...

when you type `scoped_lock<mutex> lock(_sync)` everybody reading your code knows what is going on, and you will also if you look at your code two years from know. Laziness is usually a bad motivation to create implementation. Unless you want to enforce usage, have more than just hundreds of places where you need to write this expression, just don't do it

In the time it took you to write up the question, and the amount of time that you spent pondering how to do it, and the amount of time all of us took to answer your question you probably could have written all the `scoped_lock<mutex> lock(_sync)` that you needed. Especially if you are using your IDEs completions support.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, not trying to be daft how would you improve it ?

Comment: The reason why I want to do it this way is because I do a lot of my development in C# and 99% of the guys working here are working in C# too. In C# you call `lock(_sync){...}` and everybody knows what's going on, it's pretty simple. Having this shortcut makes looking at C++ code less "foreign" (and it's faster to type).

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought that your lock will be compiled away altogether.

The point of the scoped lock is that it exists locally, so you must declare it locally.  I don't think there is a way of getting round this in c++ without macros (which just hides the code somewhere else).

I reckon use a typedef, then everyone knows what you are doing.

```
typedef scoped_lock<mutex> lock; //at the start of your class
lock l(_sync); //in your function.
```

I don't think this is so bad....

Comment: I had such a typedef once. But I kept misusing it like this: `lock(_sync)`, which locks and immediately unlocks. Then I created a macro just like Yochai Timmer.